# Using existing AspNet.Identity (MVC) in new .NetCore API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have MVC project with AspNet.Identity. Now I want to create .NetCore API with the same DB and user logins. Is it possible to use existing MVC AspNet.Identity in new .NetCore API project? I can not find any tutorial.

--EDIT--

I think I found a workaround.

In my MVC Account controller I created another login method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<JsonResult> LoginApi(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false });
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
        model.Email,
        model.Password,
        model.RememberMe,
        shouldLockout: false);

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return Json(new { success = true });
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return Json(new { success = false, lockout = true });
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return Json(new { success = false, requestVerification = true });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            return Json(new { success = false });
    }
}
```

This method is called from .netCore API. If the credentials passed to the .netCore API are correct, then tha MVC Login returns true. Based on this I can create a JWC token and handle user api request in .netCore.

Do you see any possible security risk?

--END EDIT---

Thank you.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/membership-to-core-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: Use this sample :https://dotnetdetail.net/asp-net-core-3-0-web-api-token-based-authentication-example-using-jwt-in-vs2019/

Comment: Its not what I need. I am running two MVC sites upon a single database. Now I want to add API which is going to operate with this database too. Only thing I need is to create API Login method which will decide if the username and password is correct.

Comment: not sure how to do that with aspnet identity. but maybe identityserver is something for you? it's usually run seperately, and can specify several clients.